c++ Using implementation of parent class
Regarding the following code, I would avoid copy paste so much code, or implement the interface class IHardware:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class IHardware
{
public:
  virtual ~IHardware() = default;
  virtual uint8_t GetHardwareData() const = 0; // I would to keep it pure virtual to beiong able to mock it
  // I could use: uint8_t GetHardwareData() const { return 50; } and delete Hardware implementation class
};

class ISoftwareA : public IHardware
{
public:
  virtual ~ISoftwareA() = default;
  virtual uint8_t GetSoftwareData() const = 0;
};

class ISoftwareB : public IHardware
{
public:
  virtual ~ISoftwareB() = default;
  virtual std::string GetSoftwareData() const = 0;
};

class Hardware : public IHardware // I want to keep this to let the possibility to change the hardware implementation
{
  uint8_t return_value_ = 50;
public:
  uint8_t GetHardwareData() const override { return return_value_; }
};

class TestA final : public ISoftwareA, public Hardware
{
public:
  uint8_t GetSoftwareData() const override { return 10; };
  uint8_t GetHardwareData() const override { return Hardware::GetHardwareData(); } // <- All TestX class will not override it, and I don't want to copy paste and override in every class
};

class TestB final : public ISoftwareB
{
public:
  std::string GetSoftwareData() const override { return "test"; }
  // Is there a way to use Hardware implementation ??
};

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
  TestA test_a;
  TestB test_b;

  std::cout << std::to_string(test_a.GetHardwareData()) << '\n';
  std::cout << std::to_string(test_a.GetSoftwareData()) << '\n';
  std::cout << std::to_string(test_b.GetHardwareData()) << '\n';
  std::cout << test_b.GetSoftwareData() << '\n';
}

I would like to being able to use implementation of parent class (see comment in code). Can TestB class use implementation of Hardware class
Is that even possible?

fyi TestA has diamond of death problem

why can't you just put a Hardware as a member of TestB and forward the calls ? you know C++ classes can have members ....

Do TestA really need to override GetHardwareData?

As for TestB, the only way it can have a member function with the name GetHardwareData is to either implement it yourself, or by using inheritance from a base-class that have it implemented.

Regarding your design, why should software have hardware-data? And what is the reason to have both ISoftwareA and ISoftwareB, when they are identical?

@Someprogrammerdude They're not identical. ISoftwareB:: GetSoftwareData returns std::string

You can define the software interfaces to include IHardware as a dependency rather than inheriting from it.

You should be aware of the diamond problem, which requires you to add those overrides unless all classes were modified to virtually inherit IHardware
class ISoftwareA : public virtual IHardware
...
class ISoftwareB : public virtual IHardware
...
class Hardware : public virtual IHardware
...

class TestB final : public ISoftwareB, public Hardware
{
public:
  std::string GetSoftwareData() const override { return "test"; }
  // GetHardwareData taken from Hardware
};

godbolt demo

Hello, this seems to be the solution (I didn't know about Diamond problem, but it make sense). But now I got the warning C4250 (with /W3 option in MSVC) I have probably to implement everything then. Maybe I will disable this warning

@LoganGallois this warning is if ISoftwareB implements GetHardwareData in the future your code will not compile because of ambigious call , if this is not a concern for you then you can disable that warning
